# How should I specify a boolean value in SalesForce input in Pentaho Spoon?

Tags: soap-api, etl

UPDATE: I got passed the error in Pentaho, but I still need help. Specifically, I modified the datatype of the IsActive field in my LDAP Input and Excel Output widgets. Now when I set the value of IsActive to false, Spoon no longer errors; however, in Salesforce the imported account is Active (not what I want). Suggestions?

I'm using Pentaho Spoon to insert data from Active Directory to the user module in Salesforce. I have a "Set field value to a constant" transformation that sets the values of several fields including the "IsActive" field.

I have tried specifying FALSE, false, 0, N for this value, but in each case I get an error like this: "INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD Error message: Active: value not of required type: false".

If I don't set a value for IsActive, the import works, but the users are added as Active (not what I want). What do I need to do in order to be able to set IsActive to false?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I didn't realize that the admin for the Salesforce account had a script that sets the Active property to true for newly created accounts. Doh.